# C# Having issues with UIAutomation Reference- get_BoundingRectangle() method not found

Tags: c#

Creating a C# Console app in VS 20019

I have imported 
UIAutomationTypes
&
UIAutomationClient

I try to add my Handler

```
Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
               eventId: WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
               element: AutomationElement.RootElement,
               scope: TreeScope.Children,
               eventHandler: OnWindowOpened);
```

When running the application I get the error

*System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'System.Windows.Rect System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IRawElementProviderFragment.get_BoundingRectangle()'.
  Source=
  StackTrace:*

I have not programmed in a few years, any help would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i just changed from .net core 6 to 4.8 and it became ok :)